# How to execute several reactive functions based on reactive if statement

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, reactive

I am building my first Shiny interactive App on Bikesharing Data from https://www.kaggle.com/c/bike-sharing-demand. The user can select 'Start Station' or 'End Station' with a radiobutton and should then receive Circle Markers on a Map with the radius being the count a certain Bike Station was the Start/End of a trip on a particular day.

I have one data frame with trip data (df.trip) and one data frame with the coordinates of each station (df.station). Based on the user's choice I will have to left join df.station either using 'from_station_id' or 'to_station_id' in order to find the coordinates of the start/end station.

I have implemented the radiobuttons in the UI and already have the date functionality. However, I have tried many options to get a reactive if statement that joins the dataframe on a different key based on the user selection. Within the if there are other reactive statements as well. Provided below is part of the server.

I received
`Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)`

`````
    station_type <- reactive({
     if (toString(input$station)=="Start Station") {
       return(TRUE)
     } else {
       return(FALSE)
     }
   })


   if (station_type() == TRUE) {
     filtered <- reactive({
       df.trip %>%
         filter(format(df.trip$starttime,"%Y-%m-%d") == input$date) %>%
         group_by(from_station_id) %>%
         summarize(n_trips = n())
     )}

     tmp.df <- reactive({
         left_join(filtered(), df.station, by = c("from_station_id" = "station_id"))
       })

     leaflet(tmp.df()) %>%
       addTiles(group="OSM") %>%#OSM is default tile providor
       addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
       setView(
         lng=-122.335167,
         lat=47.608013,
         zoom=12
       )%>%
       addCircleMarkers(lng = ~long, lat = ~lat, weight = 1,label=~name,
                        radius = ~n_trips)
   }

   else {
     filtered <- reactive({
       df.trip %>%
         filter(format(df.trip$starttime,"%Y-%m-%d") == input$date) %>%
         group_by(to_station_id) %>%
         summarize(n_trips = n())
     )}

     tmp.df <- reactive({
       left_join(filtered(), df.station, by = c("to_station_id" = "station_id"))
     })

     leaflet(tmp.df()) %>%
       addTiles(group="OSM") %>%#OSM is default tile providor
       addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
       setView(
         lng=-122.335167,
         lat=47.608013,
         zoom=12
       )%>%
       addCircleMarkers(lng = ~long, lat = ~lat, weight = 1,label=~name,
                        radius = ~n_trips)
   }



   })````
`````

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to you trying to render the leaflet map outside of a `renderLeaflet` function. You can also reduce the `if` section down to just the relevant part and have it all inside your `renderLeaflet` call.

So if you've set up the leaflet map in the UI with `leafletOutput(outputId = "map")`, this should work for you in the server:

```
output$map <- renderLeaflet({

  from_to <- input$station

  df <- df.trip %>%
    filter(format(df.trip$starttime,"%Y-%m-%d") == input$date)

  if (from_to == "Start Station") {
    df <- df %>% 
      group_by(from_station_id) %>%
      summarize(n_trips = n()) %>% 
      left_join(df.station, by = c("from_station_id" = "station_id"))
  } else {
    df <- df %>% 
      group_by(to_station_id) %>%
      summarize(n_trips = n()) %>% 
      left_join(df.station, by = c("to_station_id" = "station_id"))
  }

  leaflet(df) %>%
    addTiles(group="OSM") %>%#OSM is default tile providor
    addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
    setView(
      lng=-122.335167,
      lat=47.608013,
      zoom=12
    )%>%
    addCircleMarkers(lng = ~long, lat = ~lat, weight = 1,
                     label=~name, radius = ~n_trips)
})
```